# How does one prevent MS Access from concatenating the schema and table names thereby taking them over the 64 character limit?

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, odbc

I have been trying to get around this for several day's now with no luck. I loaded Libre Office to see how that would handle it, and  its native support for PostgeSQL works wonderfully and I can see the true data structure. Which is how I found out I was dealing with more than one table. What I am seeing in MS Access is the two names concatenated together. The concatenation takes them over the 64 character limit that appears to be built into the ODBC driver. I have seen many references to modifying `namedatalen` on the server side, but my problem is on the ODBC side. Most of the tables are under the 64 character limit even with the concatenation and work fine. As such I know everything else is working.  The specific error I am getting is

> `'your_extra_long_schema_name_your_table_name_that_you_want_to_get_data_from'`
>   is not a valid name. Make sure it does not include invalid characters
>   or punctuation and that it is not too long.

[image]

Comment: I just tried a test with nested (partitioned) PostgreSQL tables and Access did not concatenate the (sub-)table names. However, I did reproduce that error message when the *schema* name + master_table_name exceeded 64 characters. Could that be the actual source of your error?

Comment: Yes, that could be it. I am not familiar with PosgreSQL, and how things are named.

Comment: I added a screen shot of how the Tables look in Libre to clearify. I was assuming they were nested, but could be schema name + master_table_name

Comment: I used Marshal SQL Utility which also uses the ODBC driver, and it works fine.... So, looks like it is not ODBC it is Access. In Marshal they are separated with period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object names in an Access database are limited to 64 characters (ref: [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2010-specifications-1e521481-7f9a-46f7-8ed9-ea9dff1fa854?CorrelationId=a8d7318e-c2d5-48bb-a7d7-96e351dd924c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010341462)). When creating an ODBC linked table in the Access UI the default behaviour is to concatenate the schema name and table name with an underscore and use that as the linked table name so, for example, the remote table `table1` in the schema `public` would produce a linked table in Access named `public_table1`. If such a name exceeds 64 characters then Access will throw an error.

However, we can use VBA to create the table link with a shorter name, like so:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub so38999346()
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", "ODBC;DSN=PostgreSQL35W", acTable, _
            "public.hodor_hodor_hodor_hodor_hodor_hodor_hodor_hodor_hodor_hodor", _
            "hodor_linked_table"
End Sub
```

(Tested with Access 2010.)